# Hadoop remote csharp code execution

Tags: c#, hadoop

I've not done any development in Hadoop but I am considering looking into it for a neural network hobby project I'm working on.

I understand that hadoop allows data to be stored, managed and processed over a number of machines.

I want execute code that will create neural networks on each machine, train and then return the best network back to the server.

What want to know is if I could use Hadoop to execute csharp or c++ code on all machines? If so how could this be done?

I'd appreciate any help and advice offered.

Comment: This is probably the wrong stack for this question. Maybe try http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: Phone app won't let me post to programmers. I get a weird Java exception.

Comment: @Sippy this question is a poor fit for Programmers - it would be quickly voted down and closed over there, see [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/7274/31260) Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Comment: Rather than criticise the wording of my question. Would you chaps be good enough to offer some specific areas of improvement? Perhaps you could be so kind as to make some amendments to the original question? That way I can work on improving my future queries. :-)

Comment: I don't use programmers, I just read the basic description and as this is a conceptual question that was my best guess. As this isn't an actual code problem it's not suited toward Stack Overflow, as far as I am aware.

Comment: The only thing wrong with your question is that it doesn't show a lot of research effort into the use of Hadoop in this example, exactly what gnat's link talks about. If you spend a little more time researching how you might do this, you can then ask for advice on `programmers` as to your intended method, I assume.

Comment: Hi Sippy, point taken but in this instance I wanted to enquire before I research this myself. I wanted to see if this is possible and if so I would look into it further.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. Have a look at "Hadoop MapReduce Streaming".

This allows any executables of yours to be used as mapper or reducer.

It works like this:

- You provide a console application (C++, C# or whatever you have) that accepts input from Stdin, processes it, and writes its results to Stdout.
- You pass this executable and your input data as parameters to hadoop-streaming.jar.
- Hadoop deploys your executables to your nodes, passes chunks of input data to each one, and lets them write output.
- If you want, you can provide your own reducer the same way.

See this tutorial for more details: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-hadoop-develop-deploy-streaming-jobs/

Or the official Apache documentation: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-streaming/HadoopStreaming.html

By the way - keep off Microsoft's Mapreduce.SDK. This seems promising at first, but seems to be a dead project.

In your case you may want to implement the training and testing of an ANN as mapper, writing the evaluation results as output. You can either download and inspect all those results manually, or provide a reducer, that picks the best network and writes only that one to the final result data.